# How I can use substring in cursor?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-query

I have a `Cursor` that `Select from sqlite`, in this `query` I do a `substring` but I can'y use from `substring` it don't get me any error but show me `listView` empty.

```
    try {
        String value = editText.getText().toString();
        cursor = sql.rawQuery(
                "SELECT MetaDataID,Data,CategoryID,ParentID FROM Book WHERE Data LIKE '"
                        + "%" + value + "%'", null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Struct_Search note = new Struct_Search();
                    note.MetaData = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("MetaDataID"));
                    Result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Data"));
                    int A = Result.indexOf(value);
                    String V = Result.substring(A,100);
                    note.Value = V;
                    note.NumberAyeh = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("CategoryID"));
                    ParentID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ParentID"));
                    CursorSecond = sql.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM ContentList WHERE id ="+ ParentID, null);
                    if (CursorSecond != null) {
                        do {
                            CursorSecond.moveToFirst();
                            note.NameSureh = CursorSecond.getString(CursorSecond.getColumnIndex("name"));
                            CursorSecond.close();
                        } while (CursorSecond.moveToNext());
                    }
                    notes.add(note);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Notice : This line don't work :

```
                String V = Result.substring(A,100);
                note.Value = V;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the FIRST 100 characters AFTER index of character, and set note.Value to it, change your substring to be

```
 // substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
 Result.substring(A, A + 100);
```

In java, the second parameter of substring is endIndex, not Length.

Comment: @A.A See edit, java substring second parameter is end index, Not length. I also recommend logging things, so you can see what the value of `A` is. So that an index is found.

Comment: @A.A Good :) No problem.